# What exception type shall a Jackson Converter throw to indicate an invalid value

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

With the following annotation, I can tell Jackson to use a `Converter` class for additional post-processing on deserialized data:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(converter = MyConverter.class)
public MyConstrainedMap property;
```

For example, the following converter would convert a map to a custom type `MyConstrainedMap`:

```java
public static class MyConverter extends StdConverter<Map<String, Object>, MyConstrainedMap> {

    @Override
    public MyConstrainedMap convert(Map<String, Object> rawMap) {
        // ... check values
        return new MyConstrainedMap(rawMap);
    }
}
```

My question is: What should I do if the conversion is not possible? It would make sense to throw one of Jackson's exceptions, e.g. `JsonMappingException`, but that exception is checked, and `convert` does not allow any checked exceptions.

So what should I do instead. Throw a `RuntimeException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The answer is pretty simple, but since I couldn't find anything on this question in the Internet, I thought that I'd share it anyway.)

**Yes**, throwing any `RuntimeException` is the right thing to do if something cannot be converted. This exception will then be wrapped in a `JsonMappingException` by Jackson, and so the resulting behaviour is the same as with other parsing errors.